# font awesome icons not always displaying in the latest Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-awesome

I am using the latest Google Chrome. As soon as it was released I noticed that some of the font-awesome icons do not show correctly. Instead I just see a square box. This does not change even after all the page has loaded and I wait one minute. When I hover over them then the icons appear.

This can be seen by going to the following URL:

http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Is anyone else noticing this. I assume it effects everyone who has the new browser. Note that one day it works and shows them all, the next day there are some icons I don't see. Maybe it's an issue with timing. I have a fairly slow connection.

Comment: did u check on another browsers....?

Comment: It's Chrome 32 version problem..
Check this link ------- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332958

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the 32 version has a LOT of problem. I have drop down selects with no scroll bar where I cannot even access some items unless I use the arrow buttons. Scroll bar just stuck. I cannot believe there could be so many simple problems with the browser :-(

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336075

Comment: but yea, I haven't been too happy with this latest chrome release. I seem to be running into a lot of bugs with rendering.

Comment: Experienced the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 when compiling font-awesome.less with Grunt. Icons display in Firefox but return a 404 error in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem deals with some chrome extensions. In my case I have disabled Adblock Plus and all icons are shown now.

Comment: Here the same, with another extension. After disabling it, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug using Chrome in a Windows machine.
Reorder the font formats in your @font-face so that WOFF is placed before TTF and SVG.

SVG fonts render better in the browsers that support them. Therefore you should put them first by default.

Answer (score 0):

I saw icons in some browsers and machines but not on others. After trying moving markup around, ensuring `fa fa-*` classes were on each `i` tag and confirming html5shiv.js was included at the end of the DOM, I simply changed the CSS to use the CDN and it worked. This upgraded me from version 4.1 to 4.2.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

For icons issue you can add the following code under .htaccess file or index.php file.

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score -2):

place `!important`

```
[class^="fi-"], [class*=" fi-"] {
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: foundation-icons !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```